# how to retrieve two records in a table for each record in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a "reply" table with structure.

replyno topicno replydesc replyrank

Now i need to retrieve top 2 records ordered by replyrank in descending order (means first 2 high ranked records) for each topicno (which is a foreign key).

I need a query in mysql that can extract result set like this for all topic numbers.

please give me optimized query that can execute faster

Comment: what did you try? did you get any error? please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT replyno, topicno, replydesc, replyrank 
FROM (SELECT replyno, topicno, replydesc, replyrank, 
             IF(@topicno = @topicno:=topicno, @id:=@id+1, @id:=1) AS id 
      FROM reply, (SELECT @id:=1, @topicno:=0) A 
      ORDER BY topicno, replyrank DESC
     ) AS A 
WHERE id <= 2;
```

Comment: this query working fine, but execution time is above 13 seconds for table size of 400,000+ records. any optimization in query!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query i think it gonna work for you

```
 SELECT replyno, topicno FROM reply ORDER BY replyrank DESC LIMIT 2
```